# String instead of JSON when performing ajax request to django server

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, json

views.py:

```
def get_accounts( request ):
    if request.is_ajax():
        res = ["foo","bar"]
        json = simplejson.dumps(res)
        return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
    return HttpResponseNotFound
```

urls.py:

```
   ( r'^get_accounts/$', 'get_accounts'),
```

client.html:

```
$.get('/django/backoffice/bopanel/get_accounts',{'acc':$('.nr').text().replace(/^\s+||\s+$/g,'')}, function(data) {
  alert(data[0]);      
  });
```

I was very surprised getting an alert box with content:

```
"["
```

What means I got string instead of array, which i very strange for me and definitely not something what i expected.

In firebug i see two subsequent GET requests:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/django/backoffice/bopanel/...nts?acc=17114%2FF01055%2FTP%0A%09%09++++++++++++
301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
    24ms

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/django/backoffice/bopanel/...ts/?acc=17114%2FF01055%2FTP%0A%09%09++++++++++++
200 OK
    16ms
```

I don't understand why I get two requests and why the first have 301 status. I don't understand how this makes json appear as string. Any help?

Comment: JSON is ALWAYS a string. ALWAYS.

Comment: Sorry Ignacio, but I would expect to get "foo" printed in alert instead of "[". This is how jquery works - json string is evaluated and passed to function executed on success.

Comment: Aaaand... where do you evaluate it?

Comment: I don't have to. It's jQuery job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why I get two requests and why the first have 301 status.

Django by default appends a slash to any URL without one (see [common middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.common)).

You want to use `content_type` instead of `mimetype`, ie:

```
return http.HttpResponse(json.dumps(res), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Great, thanks - that solves the problem with two requests. Still, I dont understand why json string is not evaluated by jQuery.

Comment: I think that parsing json was added in jquery 1.4.2, which version do you use?

Comment: That was it! I thought parsing json is one of jquery basic features. Anyway, thanks a lot!